# how to stop printing else in if

Tags: python, if-statement

```
var1=20

if var1>18:
    print("you can drive")

if var1==18:
    print("you can too drive")

if var1 > 30:
    print("your age is more")

else:
    print("you cannot drive ")
```

Comment: Here is this code I'm getting two outout.1) you can drive. 2)  you can not drive... Why I am getting the 2nd output? It is for if var2 < 18

Comment: You need to use elif for the 2nd and 3rd if conditions

Comment: @user56700 thank you for showing my error.. Please help me on my output.. Why I am getting two outputs

Comment: You're getting that output because that's exactly what you coded. If var1 == 20 then both conditions *var1 > 18* and *var1 <= 30* are True

Comment: @AshNazg you are right.. But I am trying with only if not with elif conditions

Comment: @MohitMishra Please see my answer, it's not using any elif.

Comment: Please do _not_ edit your question in ways that invalidate existing answers.

Comment: Your edit exhibited the same issue as the original code anyway. You hade two separate conditional statements, permitting the possibility of two different prints.

Answer (score 2):

You likely meant to use some `elif`s. As it stands, let's add some breaks to show how your code looks to the interpreter: three *separate* conditional statements rather than one.

```
var1 = 20

if var1 > 18:
    print("you can drive")

###################################

if var1 == 18:
    print("you can too drive")

###################################

if var1 > 30:
    print("your age is more")

else:
    print("you cannot drive ")
```

If `var1` is less than or equal to `30`, `"your cannot drive"` will print.

You want:

```
var1 = 20

if var1 > 18:
    print("you can drive")
elif var1 == 18:
    print("you can too drive")
elif var1 > 30:
    print("your age is more")
else:
    print("you cannot drive ")
```

Now it's all one statement. Each condition can assume all of the preceding conditions were `False`, otherwise that condition would not be evaluated. Thus the `else` knows that `var1` was *not* greater than `18`, *not* equal to `18`, and *not* greater than `30`. The only thing it could still be is less than `18`.

---

If for whatever reason you decide that makes too much sense, and want to avoid `elif`, you need to ensure that short of `var1` being modified between conditional statements, only one of them can be true. Mostly this means verifying that `"you can drive"` can only be printed if `var` is *both* greater than `18` *and* less than `30`. It also means only printing `"you cannot drive"` after explicitly checking that `var1` is less than `18`.

```py
var1 = 20

if var1 > 18 and var1 <= 30:
    print("you can drive")

if var1 == 18:
    print("you can too drive")

if var1 > 30:
    print("your age is more")

if var1 < 18:
    print("you cannot drive ")
```

Comment: Yeah your point is true.. But here I have var1=20 which is more than 18.. So the output should be "you can drive".. But why my interpreter is printing the last condition(else)... I'm getting two output 1) " You can drive. 2) you cannot drive... Why I am getting the 2nd output?.. I should only get 2nd one only if my var1<18.. But here my var1 is 20 which is greater.

Comment: `var1` _is_ greater than `18`, so it prints `"your can drive"`, but the last if/else is a separate statement, so it considers that `var1` is _not_ greater than `30` and prints `"you cannot drive "`.

Answer (score 0):

As per your comment, if you **only** want to use if and not elif, then this might be a solution:

```py
var1 = 20

if var1 > 18:
    if var1 > 30:
        print("your age is more")
    else:
        print("you can drive")
if var1 == 18:
    print("you can drive too")
if var1 < 18:
    print("you cannot drive ")
```

Result:

```
input: 20
you can drive
input: 31
your age is more
```

Answer (score -1):

After correcting the syntax errors, you are getting two outputs because the else is considered for the last if condition, not the first one. I think what you want to implement though looks like this:

```
var1=20

if var1>18: print("you can drive")

elif var1==18: print("you can too drive")

elif var1 > 30: print("your age is more")

else: print("you cannot drive ")
```